# Problem passing company to header through report_action (report created from a wizard)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am facing a problem passing the `company_id` to the report so that it can be used to generate the header for the report in the right way:

```
<template id="module.report_this_and_that">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
```

How do I pass `company_id` to the header through `report_action()` (a wizard is creating the report):

```
data = {
            'ids': self.ids,
            'model': self._name,
            'form_data': self.read()[0],
            'vals': vals,
        }
        return self.env.ref('module.report_this_and_that_action').report_action(self, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `company_id` field to your wizard.

```
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id, string='Company')
```

It will be available in your 'from_data' key.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Comment: I already have a `company_id` field, still does not pass anything through to the view the problem should be something related to `docs`

Answer (score 0):

`data` values are available in the render context.

To use the company name in the report template, first, add it to to `data`:

```
data = {
    'company_name': company_id.name
    ...
}

return self.env.ref('module.report_this_and_that_action').report_action(self, data=data)
```

Then use `company_name` like following:

```
<span t-esc='company_name'/>
```

Comment: Eventually I resorted to that, but what if I want to use the `web.external_layout`? isn't there a way to pass company informations through: `<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">`  `<t t-call="web.external_layout">` like you would on a regular report.

Comment: You can alter the local context to  define  new variables, check [calling sub-templates](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#calling-sub-templates) for more details